# What can be the problem with my haskell code and how can I fix it?

Tags: haskell

> deadNeighbors:
> Give a list of empty cells that have a living cellular neighbor in that generation. Make sure that each cell is listed only once!

Something not work with my deadNeighbors function, but I do not know what is wrong about it. Can anybody help me to fix deadNeighbors ?

```
type Coordinate = (Integer, Integer)

type Generation = [Coordinate]

single :: Generation
single = [ (42, 42) ]

row :: Generation
row = [ (10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 3) ]
```

Code:

```
neighbors :: Coordinate -> [Coordinate]
neighbors (x,y) = [(x-1,y-1), (x-1,y), (x-1,y+1), (x ,y-1), (x,y+1), (x+1,y-1), (x+1,y), (x+1,y+1)]

alive :: Generation -> Coordinate -> Bool 
alive x y = elem y x  

livingNeighbors :: Generation -> Coordinate -> Int
livingNeighbors a = length .filter (alive a) . neighbors

staysAlive :: Generation -> Coordinate -> Bool
staysAlive a b
 | alive a b = livingNeighbors a b `elem` [2,3]
 | otherwise = livingNeighbors a b `elem` [3]
```

Problems:

```
deadNeighbors :: Generation -> [Coordinate]
deadNeighbors (neighbors (x,y)) 
 |(alive (x,y)) = Nothing
 |otherwise = [] ++ (x,y)
```

Examples:

```
sort (deadNeighbors single) == sort [(41.41), (41.42), (41.43), (42.41), (42.43), (43.41), (43.42) , (43.43)]
sort (deadNeighbors row) == sort [(9.0), (9.1), (9.2), (10.0), (11.0), (11.1), (11.2) , (9.3), (11.3), (9.4), (10.4), (11.4)]
```

Comment: Please focus your question one of these functions, ask a more specific questions, and show error messages that you are getting. Also, it would be nice if you could limit the code you include in your question to just the bare minimum that somebody would need to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go over `deadNeighbors` function line by line:

(the type signature looks fine)

```
deadNeighbors (neighbors (x,y))
```

This is a clause of the `deadNeighbors` function and seems to use pattern matching notation, however you use the function `neighbors` in the pattern match. That is not allowed. I don't really know what your intention is here, so I cannot suggest a way to fix this.

```
 |(alive (x,y)) = Nothing
```

Here you are using a guard correctly, but the `alive` function requires the generation in addition to the coordinate. You should pass both as arguments here.

Also, you are returning `Nothing` which has type `Maybe a` for some `a`. But the signature of the `deadNeighbors` function indicates it should return a `[Coordinate]`. Perhaps you intended to write `[]` (the empty list)?

```
 |otherwise = [] ++ (x,y)
```

Here you are using the `++` operator, which expects two lists as arguments, with an empty list `[]` as argument and a coordinate `(x,y)`. The coordinate type is not a list, so it is not compatible with the `++` operator. Perhaps you intended `(x,y) : []` or just `[(x,y)]` (which means the same thing but is slightly prettier)?

Comment: In the first part I would like to give  the neighbors list to my function.

Comment: The neighbors list of which point? And what do you want to do with the resulting list of neighbors?

Comment: The point x,y what I give. So I would like to collect the dead neighbors from the neighbors list of the point (x,y).

Comment: The function gets a whole generation as input, not a single point. I think you might want to do something for every alive cell in the given generation. So not just do something for a single cell. Although you could do that with the `map` function and a helper function that does something for each individual cell.